# Lodash difference between _.remove() and _.pullAt()

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

What is the difference between lodash `_.remove()` and `_.pullAt()` functions?

```
var arr1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
_.remove(arr1, function (item) {
  return item == 1
});

var arr2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
_.pullAt(arr2, 1);

console.log(arr1.toString() + '\n' + arr2.toString());

// both result to [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,]
```

I've crated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/burim/5kzc8xgm/) and read the description on the lodash site that states that _.remove()

> Removes all elements from array that predicate returns truthy for and returns an array of the removed elements

and _.pullAt()

> Removes elements from array corresponding to the given indexes and returns an array of the removed elements

Is there any difference at all? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You mean other than `__.remove()` uses a predicate and `__.pullAt` uses indices?

Comment: try to remove all even numbers with `pullAt`

Comment: Your documentation quote explicitly stated the differences. Just because you can create equivalence in output doesn't mean they're the same. Re-read the docs.

Comment: also check your example with `[9, 8, 7, 1]` array

Comment: @vp_arth thank you, this last one helped

Comment: Says it in what you posted *that predicate returns truthy* and *corresponding to the given indexes*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even your example made different things:

`remove` splices element **by value**, while `pullAt` **by index**.

Let's check it with different array `[0, 3, 1, 1, 5]`:

- `remove`: `[0, 3, 5]` - all `1` items removed
- `pullAt`: `[0, 1, 1, 5]` - `arr[1]` was spliced

You also can write other filters than compare by value with `remove`:

```
_.remove(arr, item => item % 2); // removes all odd numbers
_.remove(arr, user => user.deleted); // splice deleted users
_.remove(arr, item => item < 5); // and etc.
```